# VSTO : how to set a ribbon's button from ThisAddIn class

Tags: c#, class, vsto, ribbon

I have a ribbon, that has button in it.
When a user selects new document, I would like to change the ribbon's button's text.
I think I've done everything but one line:

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var wb = this.Application;
        ((Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event)wb).NewDocument += new Word.ApplicationEvents4_NewDocumentEventHandler(Application_NewDocument);

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// When the new button is pressed, the save should be enabled
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Doc"></param>
    void Application_NewDocument(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Doc)
    {
    // set button's properties here
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most easy way is to put the event handler in the `Ribbon` class. Then you can simply use:

```
this.Button.Label = "text";
```

Else, you have to create a property marshaling it to the outside world:

In Ribbon:

```
public string ButtonText {get {return this.Button.Label;} set {this.Button.Label = value;} }
```

In ThisAddIn:

```
Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon.ButtonText = "text";
```

Comment: It also works: Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.btnSave.Enabled = true;

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the ribbon callback event "getlabel" to set the text. In the Newdocument event set the variable name as shown in the sample code below and then call ribbon [InvalidateControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidatecontrol%28v=office.15%29.aspx) which will repaint your ribbon and executes the callback.

**Ribbon.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabAddIns" label="3rd Party Add-ins" />      
          <button id="btnTest" onAction="btnTest_Click" getLabel="get_LabelName" size="large" />        
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

**Ribbon.cs**

```
public class Ribbon : IRibbonExtensibility
{
    private static IRibbonUI ribbon;
    private string buttonText;
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var wb = this.Application;
        ((Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event)wb).NewDocument += new Word.ApplicationEvents4_NewDocumentEventHandler(Application_NewDocument);

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// When the new button is pressed, the save should be enabled
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Doc"></param>
    void Application_NewDocument(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Doc)
    {
        buttonText = "New Document Created";
        ribbon.InvalidateControl("btnTest");
    }

     public string get_LabelName(IRibbonControl control)
    {
        return buttonText;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Application_NewDocument` and `Application_NewDocument` events are in `ThisAddIn` class. But, you are showing them in `Ribbon.cs` class. Your suggestion would not work in `Ribbbon XML` case. ` ribbon.InvalidateControl("...");` is not available in `ThisAddIn` class. Also, OP seems to be using `Ribbon Designer` and not `Ribbon XML`. So, accepted answer should work.